adjust height of the container in html
enter image description hereim trying to adjust the height of the dash container ( white ) but icant seems to figure how to do it , this code and i would appreciate any help :
analytics.html :
{% extends 'frontend/base.html' %}
{% load plotly_dash %}

{% block content %}
    <h2>Reports and Analytics</h2>
    <div id="dash-container" style="width: 100%; height: 1200px; overflow: hidden;">  <!-- Adjust container height here -->
        {% plotly_app name="Analytics" %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}

analytics_dash.py :
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from django_plotly_dash import DjangoDash
from .models import UserAction
from django.db.models import Count

# Create a Django Dash application
app = DjangoDash('Analytics')

def load_data():
    actions = UserAction.objects.values('action_type').annotate(count=Count('id'))
    return [action['action_type'] for action in actions], [action['count'] for action in actions]

# Define the layout of the Dash app
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(
        id='user-action-graph',
        style={'width': '100%', 'height': '100%'}  # Use 100% to fill container
    )
], style={'width': '100%', 'height': '1200px'})  # Adjust to match container size

@app.callback(
    Output('user-action-graph', 'figure'),
    [Input('user-action-graph', 'id')]
)
def update_graph(_):
    action_types, counts = load_data()

    fig = go.Figure()

    if not action_types or not counts:
        fig.add_annotation(text="No Activity Data Available Yet", showarrow=False)
    else:
        fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
            x=action_types, 
            y=counts, 
            marker=dict(color='royalblue', line=dict(color='black', width=1))
        ))

    max_count = max(counts) if counts else 5

    fig.update_layout(
        title='User Activities',
        xaxis_title='Action Type',
        yaxis_title='Count',
        yaxis=dict(range=[0, max_count + 2]),
        margin=dict(l=40, r=40, b=40, t=40),
        height=1000,  # Match height with container
    )

    return fig`

i tried to adjust the dcc graph my self , testes using min-height and max-height but nothing appeared to fix the issue and ican only manage to make the graph inside the container bigger

Setting 'height': '95vh' should work (not 100vh to prevent a vertical scrollbar) : dcc.Graph(id='user-action-graph', style={'width': '100%', 'height': '95vh'}).

im trying to adjust the height of the container but icant figure it how , if change it inside the analytics_dash.py it only affect the height of the graph inside the container but not the container itself , leading to the scrollbar to appear and in the div for container :
 
only the width modification seems to take effect , height doesnt affect at all

What happens if you set overflow: auto; to the 'dash-container' div and remove the html.Div() wrapper from the dash app layout ? ie. app.layout = dcc.Graph(id='user-action-graph', style={'width': '100%', 'height': '95vh'}). Or you can do the opposite: remove the <div id="dash-container"> from analytics.html and use only the html.Div container in the app layout.

i adjusted tha app.layout as you said and remove div from analytics.html , eneded with same thing :
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(
        id='user-action-graph',
        style={'width': '100%', 'height': '95vh', 'overflow': 'auto'}
    )
], style={'height': '95vh'}) 

seems to remove the the scroll bar and the size of the graph inside the container gets bigger without ability to scroll down and i notice that adjusting height in fig.update_layout , seems to increase the highet of the graph and not container

the only solution i found was this so far :
to explain the probleme fruther , the dash already embed the graph within page of itself so when you have {% plotly_app name="Analytics" %} inside your page , what you are doing is embedding the already embedded graph leading to not having controll over it , becuase any modification in .py file ( file repsonible for for the dash) only lead to affect the dash and doesnt apply the third layer of the page , by viewing the code source of the page where you have {% plotly_app name="Analytics" %} you can find that its already been embedded similair code to this :
 <iframe src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/django_plotly_dash/app/Analytics/" 
        style="width: 100%; height: 90vh; border: none;"></iframe>

if u just type it , instead of {% plotly_app name="Analytics" %} on your page directly , any modification inside to .py file will be applied since you no longer have 3 layered page ( one embed into onther and that one on your own page )
i couldnt find any documents about that ,maybe the use of {% plotly_app name="Analytics" %} is wrong or there might be a issue with django dash or my code itself was wrong at somewhere
{% extends 'frontend/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<h2>Reports and Analytics</h2>
<iframe src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/django_plotly_dash/app/Analytics/" 
        style="width: 100%; height: 90vh; border: none;"></iframe>
{% endblock %}
````[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/Knexh9sG.png
 


{% extends 'frontend/base.html' %}
{% load plotly_dash %}
{% block content %}
Reports and Analytics

{% endblock %}
imanage to make it work like this , idont know wether this gonna be correct for later use or not

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

i provided more explanation to what was the problem from my understanding and why my solution fixed it
